# Angular JS and Express JS Routing Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm having problems getting my NodeJS app to work with both Express JS and Angular JS, in particular I'm struggling to get the routing to work between the two.

My goal is to have ExpressJS drive the API and have Angular control the user facing routes.

Currently I have just two templates I wish to serve, the index page and the create-poll page.

Here's what I have so far,

Angular Routing -

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('showOfHands', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/index'
    }).when('/create-poll', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/create-poll'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Express Routing -

```
'use strict';

app.get( '/partials/:name', function( req, res ) {
        res.render( 'partials/' + req.params.name );
    } );

    app.get( '*', function( req, res ) { 
        res.render( 'partials/index' );
    } );
```

When I try to click on my link to create a poll, I navigate to /create-poll but the template being used remains as the index page. If I navigate manually however to partials/create-poll in the browser I'm correctly served the create-poll template but this is then handled by Express JS as opposed to Angular.

Comment: Your `app.get('*'...)` should be returning `index.html`, not `partials/index`.  In other words, It should be returning the index *page*, not your index *template*.

Comment: Thank you!, I was silly enough to put ngview as opposed to ng-view in my index page but nonetheless after changing that the route for partial kept looping round (I got 'a maximum call stack exceed' error) until I changed it to the way you suggested.